# Map through nested JavaScript objects with string key then filter list

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, filter

I have trouble to map through a nested object with string and objects, trying to get a list of the "qty" value in array so I can filter out.

data looks like this:

```
const data = {   
   '123': {
        'name': 'Part 1',
        'size': '20',
        'qty' : '50'
    },
    '5678' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '60'
    },
   '9810' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '120'
    },
 }

// my code I tried:
const getValue = Object.key(data).map(i=> [i].qty)  //undefined
// expect return ['50','60','120']

const items = ['4','120','5']

// Expecting remove '120' from this list, because the getValue should have '120' in the array.
const filterItem = items.filter(i => i !== getValue)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should be `Object.keys(data).map(i => data[i].qty)`. Your current code is creating a new array literal and trying to retrieve the `qty` property of the array, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that simply as below, check the comments to understand better:

```
const extractQuantityValues = ['120'];

const newDataValues = Object.keys(data)
 // select keys of object and keep them as array type
 .filter( i => !extractQuantityValues.includes(data[i].qty) )
 // filter the keys to get needed values that kept above,
 // if it is have no values of the your extractQuantityValues array
 .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = data[key], res), {} );
 // create new object which you need filtered values of object from the data object
```

And check the snippet which it works exactly what you need:

```js
const data = {   
   '123': {
        'name': 'Part 1',
        'size': '20',
        'qty' : '50'
    },
    '5678' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '60'
    },
   '9810' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '120'
    },
 }
 
const extractQuantityValues = ['120'];

const newDataValues = Object.keys(data)
 .filter( i => !extractQuantityValues.includes(data[i].qty) )
 .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = data[key], res), {} );

console.log(newDataValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Object.keys(data).map(i => data[i].qty)